# How would rearrange these equations to make d and a the subject?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$c = \frac{9d-8}{8+7d}   $$
$$b = \frac{7a+6}{8-9a}    $$

I have tried this question but I have always got the wrong answer.

Comment: Please show one of your attempts so we can spot the error.

Comment: Well, ok.  How do solve that for $d$?  Hint:  get all the $d$ terms on one side.

Comment: Ok, so you got to $7dc -9d=-8-8c$.  that means that $d(7c-9)=-8(1-c)$.  Can you finish from there?

Comment: c(8+7d) = 9d-8, 8c + 7dc = 9d-8, 7d-9d = -8-8c, -2d = -8-8c/c, d = -8-8c/-2c

Comment: IT worked, thank youuuu

Comment: @lulu, you have some discrepancy with signs.  @ Siddharth, you should use parentheses to make it unambiguous where numerators and denominators start and stop.  `-8-8c/-2c` could be interpreted as $-8-\frac{8c}{-2c}$ (*and should be interpreted this way usually imo*), as $\frac{-8-8c}{-2c}$ or even as $-8-\frac{8c}{-2}\cdot c$ etc...

Comment: The best way to make it perfectly clear what is intended is to type it correctly using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.  [See this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a primer on how to get started typing mathematical equations on this site correctly.

Comment: @JMoravitz  Absolutely right, I botched the signs.  Good practice for the OP!

Comment: Side note:  since I (for one) frequently make small errors (such as the sign error here) I find it an excellent idea to check by evaluating at a few numbers.  For example, taking $d=1$ gives us $c=\frac 9{15}=\frac 35$.  So if you use that value of $c$ in your proposed answer you ought to get $1$ back.  That's a good way to detect blunders!

Answer (score 0):

$$c = \frac{9d-8}{8+7d} \implies c(8+7d)=9d-8 \implies 8+8c=(9-7c)d \implies d = \frac{8+8c}{9-7c}  $$
$$b = \frac{7a+6}{8-9a} \implies b(8-9a)=7a+6 \implies 8b-6=(7-9b)a \implies a =\frac{8b-6}{7-9b}   $$